# Capitalization of the word "county"

Tags: capitalization

Which is correct when listing counties:

> - Harding, Platt, and Garner Counties
> - Harding, Platt, and Garner counties

Comment: Which country are they in?

Comment: This is the Oxford Capitalization question!

Answer (score 6):

I would be inclined to go with the second option (not capitalized), or paraphrasing to "the counties of Harding, Platt and Garner".

Answer (score 6):

I would think it would be lower-case in this case:

> Harding, Platt, and Garner counties

But upper-case when written like this:

> Harding, Platt, and Garner County

Comment: +1 for the distinction between singular and plural forms. Once you use the plural, "counties" is no longer part of the proper noun and you are essentially abbreviating and refactoring the word _county_ out of "Harding County", "Platt County", and "Garner County". Same thing would apply for, say, "Oxford and Baker streets".